# I need some new "clothes" for the summer

Tags: vocabulary

> “I need some new **clothes** for the summer.” ([Merriam-Webster’s Learner’s](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/clothes))

If the word, *clothes*, is plural, don’t you include a skirt into the clothes category? Can the speaker have in his mind for something singular, e.g.skirt; or just plural, e.g. pants, trousers?

Comment: Isn't this a little bit like asking if "I see some horses" means I only see couples of horses, excluding any individual ones? _Clothes_ is the plural of _an individual item of clothing_. An individual item of clothing _includes_ a skirt, but also a pair of pants.

Comment: Related: *[Is it correct to use “Pant” or is “Pants” better?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/32745)*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Clothes* is plural because it includes plural *items* of clothing, which may be individually expressible as either singular or plural. Whether your shopping list has a) a skirt, a blouse, a hat and a raincoat, or b) a pair of socks, a scarf and a pair of slacks, each set may be referred to as *clothes*.

But if *all* you are buying is a skirt you don't say you need new clothes; you say you need a new skirt.

Answer (score 8):

If the speaker were thinking of purchasing only one single item, they would probably name that specific item instead of saying "some (new) clothes"; they might, for example, say "I need a new skirt for the summer".

With the given sentence, it's most likely the speaker has in mind purchasing multiple items in order to have either a complete outfit, or a variety of choices: they might buy 3 or 4 skirts, or a pair of pants, and a shirt or two, and some sandals; all of which would be probably lighter in both weight and color than "normal" clothes, in order to be appropriate for summer.

So a skirt definitely falls into the "clothes" category, but I wouldn't think of just one skirt as "some clothes" in that situation.

Answer (score 1):

You could also say in singular form: "I need to buy a new *piece of clothing*" if you have not decided what type of clothing you want to buy.

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/piece_of_clothing

Answer (score -2):

Think of *clothes* as the plural of *cloth*. A simple wrap has other uses, but anything we wear is made of more than one piece of *cloth* sewn together.

If you want to go shopping but have no clear idea what you want to buy, you would say "I need some new clothes". Maybe you will buy more than one. If you have a definite plan, you say " I need **a** new skirt / pants / hat"

Comment: Hm. You're implying that, since a T-shirt is made up of two parts of cloth sewn together, you can refer to a single T-shirt as "clothes". This is not the case however.

Comment: But the plural of "cloth" is "cloths".