# Does singular or plural verb goes with plural nouns like trousers, glasses, scissors, binoculars and many more?

Tags: verbs, singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement, plural-forms

> 1. My glasses (was/were) lying on the table.
> 2. My trousers (is/are) torn.
> 3. (This/These) binoculars (was/were) gifted to me.

I know they're in plural form, but plural nouns such as rickets, measles are disease names, but they take singular verb.

Comment: Some words, such as ***trousers, glasses, scissors***, are semantically singular, but syntactically plural. Others, such as ***rickets*** and ***measles***, are semantically ***and*** syntactically singular. I suspect you may just have to *learn* these on a case-by-case basis. But many of the first group can be identified because they're often used in expressions like *a **pair** of [glasses, trousers, scissors].*

Comment: So all  above 3 sentences will be in singular verb form.

Comment: ***No!*** I said *trousers, glasses, scissors, are semantically singular (they **mean** "a single thing"), but syntactically **plural** (we use the plural verb form with them).*  So your sentences should be *My glasses **were** lying on the table, My trousers **are** torn, These binoculars **were** gifted to me*. Note that in normal conversational contexts we'd usually say ***given***, not ***gifted*** in the last one.

Comment: "Measles" can be singlar or plural.  The OED says "usually" singular.  Collins says "singular or plural".  It's easy to find recent examples of it taking the plural. E.g. Leslie DeLong & Nancy Buckhart, *General and Oral Pathology for the Dental Hygienist* (2007): "German measles are mostly commonly found in children or adults who have not been vaccinated or exposed...".

Comment: [Relevant Ngram "measles is/are"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=measles+is%2C+measles+are&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)

Comment: I'm not sure it's particularly relevant that *some* Anglophones are prepared to treat ***measles*** as plural. It's just one of OP's two *examples,* and per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rickets+are+a+disease%2Crickets+is+a+disease%2Crickets+are+diseases&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crickets%20is%20a%20disease%3B%2Cc0), neither *rickets are a disease,* nor *rickets are diseases* occur often enough to chart in NGrams (the "standard" being *rickets **is** a disease*), It's the same with ***mumps***, and doubtless others

Comment: Related answer dealing with diseases and articles: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/82976/i-got-a-stomach-flu-or-i-got-the-stomach-flu-or-i-got-stomach-flu/82986#82986 Mostly deals with diseases

Comment: Unrelated to your question:  We don't put spaces before commas in English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You have enough there for an answer

Comment: @Adam: When I wrote *you may just have to learn these on a case-by-case basis* in my first comment I half-expected / hoped someone would refute me there by setting out some general principles that might be useful (my point about ***pair*** doesn't help unless you already *know* the usage for a given word). I wasn't really expecting to be sidetracked by claims that ***measles*** isn't *always* syntactically singular (the full OED gives 15 cites for the "infectious disease" sense, none of which are "plural" usages). Diseases in general may be a relevant "syntax category" here, I don't know.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  choster tried to lay out those guidelines for clothes, with a little success - Perhaps the OP would find his attempt useful: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/32745/im-wearing-a-red-pant-or-im-wearing-a-red-pants/32763#32763

Comment: @Adam: Pouring petrol on the flames here, I'm tempted to suggest *there **is** no possible **means** to cover all usages in a small number of categories.* Not that I'm *wild* about that usage there - but if it's generally considered "unacceptable", ***that is news to me**!* :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to shamelessly repurpose the comments to answer this question:

> (FumbleFingers) Some words, such as trousers, glasses, scissors, are semantically singular, but syntactically plural. Others, such as rickets and measles, are semantically and syntactically singular. I suspect you may just have to learn these on a case-by-case basis. But many of the first group can be identified because they're often used in expressions like a pair of [glasses, trousers, scissors].  So your sentences should be:
>
> My glasses **were** lying on the table
>
> My trousers **are** torn
>
> These binoculars **were** gifted to me

Side note:

> (rjpond) "Measles" (and other diseases) can be singular or plural. The OED says "usually" singular. Collins says "singular or plural". It's easy to find recent examples of it taking the plural. E.g. Leslie DeLong & Nancy Buckhart, General and Oral Pathology for the Dental Hygienist (2007): "German measles are mostly commonly found in children or adults who have not been vaccinated or exposed...".

Side note #2:  FumbleFingers says that "these binoculars were **given** to me" is more common than "these binoculars were **gifted** to me".  I actually *prefer* to use "to gift" as a verb where appropriate, so it's likely just personal choice.

Comment: Is the use of given and gifted not dependant on context? In the original example it is clear they were gifted so now they belong to a new owner. However given could mean issued/lent and should be returned at a latter date." we were given the keys to the boss's car" Hence the use of "given" does not specify ownership, just that the object was not "acquired" by yourself.