# When should we use 'look familiar' and 'looks familiar'?

Tags: word-usage

Should I say, "those glasses looks familiar" or "those glasses look familiar". Or both can be used?

Comment: What do you think? What examples have you come across?

Comment: ***glasses*** is always syntactically ***plural***, regardless of whether it means ***one pair of spectacles*** or ***more than one drinking glass***. So it has to be "those glasses **look** familiar" in all contexts.

Comment: See [Does singular or plural verb goes with plural nouns like trousers, glasses, scissors, binoculars and many more?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/142342/does-singular-or-plural-verb-goes-with-plural-nouns-like-trousers-glasses-scis)